# How do I extract data types from an XML Schema file?

Tags: xml, types, xsd, vb.net-2010

I would like to analyze and extract from an XML Schema file(XSD) the [Primitive Data Types](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#built-in-primitive-datatypes) contained within.

i.e.

```
<xs:element name="floatValue" type="xs:float">
<xs:element name="timeValue" type="xs:Time">
<xs:element name="stringValue" type="xs:string">
<xs:element name="booleanValue" type="xs:boolean">
```

I am trying to make sure that I have coverage within my VB.NET WinForms application for the following [data types available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47zceaw7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Are there any automated tools or methods for accomplishing this outside of just running a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> on the flat files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET includes classes to parse XSD files, creating (relatively) easy to use classes - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschema.read.aspx). Using these classes you can write a program in VB.NET that extracts the information you need.

I don't know of any ready-made tool that does what you need.

Comment: I am already familiar with the .NET classes associated with working with XSDs. I was curious if anyone had run across a utility or script that might easily extract the data types without needing to create a project, write code, etc.